# How to expire a cookie on next visit using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

How to Expire a `Cookie` on next visit ? I am using the `jquery` `cookie-plugin`. I am able to do something like this.

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 1 });
```

This is for 1 day. But how can we set expiry time for the next visit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't specify an expiry time. This will make it a session cookie and the cookie will expire when the browser is closed.